# An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: windbg

Running a performance analysis on DebugDiag Analysis is failed with following message:

PerfAnalysis - v (2.3.0.37) Failed Dump File:  C:\w3wp.DMP;

Type:  System.ArgumentException

Message:  An item with the same key has already been added.

Stack Trace:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.COperations.get_BoilerPlateFunctionsByOpType()

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.COperation.AddClrFramesToRelevantStackFrames(ScriptThreadClass thread, IASPRequest vData, Dictionary`2 relevantStackFrames)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.COperation.GetRelevantStackFrames(ScriptThreadClass thread, IASPRequest vData)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.COperation.BeginInit(Int32 opType, String key, ScriptThreadClass thread, IASPRequest vData, Int32 dumpNumber)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.PerfFunctions.AddUnknownOperation(ScriptThreadClass thread, CDump dump)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.PerfFunctions.LoadOperationsForThread(ScriptThreadClass thread, CDump dump)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.PerfFunctions.LoadOperationsForDump(CDump dump, Object dumpNum, Object totalDumps)

DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.PerfAnalysis.RunAnalysisRule(NetScriptManager manager, NetProgress progress)

DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer.RunAnalysisRulesInternal(DumpFileType bitness, NetProgress progress, String symbolPath, String imagePath, String reportFileFullPath, Boolean twoTabs, AnalysisModes analysisMode)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem, and the only solution I could find was to revert the version of DebugDiag to DebugDiag Version 2 Update 2.

Link to download for this specific version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924

Comment: This version is no longer available for download, though.